# SqlCommand only returns one row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

Trying to only return the first few number of rows because my database was too big, however when I was testing my SQL, I did a `select *` and was only returned the first row.

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Log";
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;

myConnection.Open();

reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

Log logs = null;

while (reader.Read())
{
    logs = new Log();
    logs.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
}

return logs;
myConnection.Close();
```

What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: reader.GetValue(0) will always return the 0th record?

Comment: what is the value column name at position 0 ? also use the debugger to see what the records count is. does the Log have an `Add` method ?

Comment: You're replacing `logs` every iteration of the loop. You're probably looking at add to a `List<Log>` or something to that effect. As you have it, you can indeed only get one record.

Comment: Curses!  Foiled by that pesky `new` keyword...again!

Comment: Also, note that putting `myConnection.Close();` after the `return` is a bug, as that code is unreachable. Use a using or try/finally or just put it before the return.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your loop you constantly re-create the instance of the variable `logs` thus overwriting the previous one and ending with the value of the last record returned by your query. You need a `List<Log>`

```
    List<Log> logs = new List<Log>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Log current = new Log();
        logs.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
        logs.Add(current);
    }
```

You can use this list as datasource for a grid or just keep it for your future references...

```
    foreach(Log log in logs)
       MessageBox.Show(log.Id);
```

Comment: very nice indeed :)